# How does this program stop taking input?

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a C source code and to get input it does

```
 while(!feof(stdin)){
        fscanf(stdin, "%d ...
```

What I can't understand is how do you get it to stop taking input and process the input? Ctr+Z just kills the whole process and I tried pressing enter a bunch without input and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

EOF (usually a `define` with value -1) indicator on Linux will match <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (ASCII code 4) for text files. It's generic enough to be used with both binary and text files and on different environments too (for example it'll match <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for text files on DOS/Windows).

In your case loop will exit when user will type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> as input because input stream will reach its end (then [feof()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/) will return non zero).

To see drawbacks ([not so obvious behavior](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1046476070)) for this method just try yourself to input some text then `printf` it out (using various inputs, terminating at the beginning or in the middle of a line). See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for more details about that.

Better (least astonishment) implementation may avoid `fscanf` and rely on `fgets` return value (for example). Compare its behavior with this:

```
char buffer[80];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Should it be upper case d? I tried with lower case and it works on this machine.

Comment: There is not an upper case/lower case CTRL+D. It's just ASCII code 4 (CTRL-D is a shortcut to produce that code).